# ArcGIS layers not scaling when attribute table is open

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've recently discovered an issue in Chrome and I'm wondering if anyone else has had this issue or if anyone can tell me how to fix it.  Basically, when I zoom in and out on my map when the AttributeTable widget is closed, everything scales correctly as shown in the video below.

[Correctly Scaling](https://youtu.be/1HWVfDE5R4M)

However, when I open the AttributeTable and try to do the exact same thing, nothing scales correctly and begins to offset.

[Incorrectly Scaling](https://youtu.be/MCcrGRruCSo)

Has anyone else encountered this issue?  If so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Does it happen with different themes?

Comment: I haven't tried it with different themes.  Mainly because it's a standard theme we decided on, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall so I discovered that it's not an issue with the template.

Comment: Does it happen with other browsers?

Comment: It wasn't at first, but now it's happening in IE as well